# Will rounding error be random or consistent if run the same program multiple times

Tags: python, c++, floating-point

For the same underlying value, will the rounding error be consistent or random when I run a program multiply time.  Say, if I store value 0.003, the actual number stored in the computer is 0.002999999998.  If I run the same program multiple times, will the stored number be sometimes 0.002999999998, and sometimes 0.0030000000001?

Comment: Unclear. If the number stored is (say) `01110000111000110`, then... the value stays that way! Could you edit question and clarify.

Comment: And why the language tags ?

Comment: See also Bruce Dawson's "[Floating-Point Determinism](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/floating-point-determinism/)".